# How Status value active or inactive respected 1 or 0 in yii 2.0 advanced template

Tags: php

How can I filter value in Yii 2.0 version?

```
'category_status'=>[
    'filter' => ['0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'],
    'value'=>'($data->category_status==1)?"Active":"Inactive"',
],
```

I can use in but not working Yii 2.0 advanced template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care about those `quotes` in order to let it work within your array declaration or you can simply store that within a variable and use it within your array like as

```
'category_status'=>[
    'filter' => ['0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'],
    'value' =>  (($data->category_status==1)?"Active":"Inactive"),
],
```

or simply save it within another variable and simply use variable like as

```
$var = ($data->category_status==1) ? "Active" : "Inactive";
'category_status'=>[
    'filter' => ['0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'],
    'value' =>  $var,
],
```